# inheriting android styles

Tags: android, styles, commonsware

In the commonwares (4.0) book it shows how to inherit android styles...

```
<style name="activated" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

But I get "no resource found with that name.  I find documentation at..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
saying that all of the styles that can be inherited are in my R.style file - but I don't have one and don't know how to get one.

That link also has two links that show the styles and themes available but both links are broken.

So how can I inherit the various android styles and themes?
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Are you building your app with API level 11 or higher? Holo did not exist before

Answer (score 0):

> But I get "no resource found with that name

As zapi indicates, that style is new to API Level 11. You will notice that the resource in question is from a `res/values-v11/` directory, so that resource will only be used on API Level 11 or higher. There is another definition of the `activated` style resource in `res/values/` that does not inherit from `Theme.Holo`.